# JS in rails. loop each of rails then get the class in JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Hi Im creating a click button by JS which is +1 or -1 each click.

What I want to do: In rails each looping created item from @items. Get the class name in JS and edit quantity each item. How can I do?

I tried to get the Id but I know the work only first one.

[image: The point of I want to edit quantity.]

```
The part of to get class

    <div class="quantity-select">                           
        <div class="entry value-minus">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="entry value score-value"><%= uiq %></div>
        <div class="entry value-plus active">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
```

show.html.erb

```
<% @items.zip(@user_items_quantity) do | item, uiq | %>
    <tr class="rem1">
        <td class="invert-image" >
            <%= link_to image_tag(item.img.thumb.url || "sushi1.jpg", class: "img-responsive" ), item %>
        </td>

        <td class="invert">
            <%= form_with model: item.basket_items.build, url: baskets_edit_from_baskets_path(item), method: :post, remote: true do |f| %>
                <div class="quantity"> 
                    <div class="quantity-select">                           
                        <div class="entry value-minus">&nbsp;</div>
                            <div class="entry value score-value"><%= uiq %></div>
                        <div class="entry value-plus active">&nbsp;</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <%= f.hidden_field :item_id, value: item.id %>
                <%= f.hidden_field :quantity, class: "quantity-value" %>
                <%= f.submit "edit", class: "button mt-3" %>
            <% end %>
        </td>
        <td class="invert"><%= link_to item.name, item %></td>
        <td class="invert">$ <%= link_to item.price, item %></td>
        <td class="invert">
            <%= link_to image_tag("close_1.png"), item_delete_in_baskets_path(item), method: :post, data: { confirm: "You sure?" }, class:"ml-2"%>
        </td>
    </tr>

<% end %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'item_quantity.js' %>
```

my try

```
var add = document.getElementsByClassName("value-plus");
var remove = document.getElementsByClassName("value-minus");
var scoreValue = document.getElementsByClassName("score-value");

var quantityValue = document.getElementsByClassName("quantity-value");


add.addEventListener('click', function() {
  int = parseInt(scoreValue.innerHTML, 10)+1;
  quantityValue.value = int;
  scoreValue.textContent = int;
});
remove.addEventListener('click', function() {
  int = parseInt(scoreValue.innerHTML, 10)-1;
  quantityValue.value = int;
  scoreValue.textContent = int;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood because there are a mix of different programming langueges. However regarding the JS code, you can use this code as base to implement something better. I try just use the classes that you use in the HTML code.
I think this value `var quantityValue = document.getElementsByClassName("quantity-value");` should be quantity-select, or not.

**The example code:**

```js
var quantities = document.getElementsByClassName("quantity-select");
var quantityValueElement = 0;

for(let quantity of quantities){
  quantity.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    let clickedDivQuantitySelect = event.target.parentElement;
    let classNameOperator = event.target.className;
    quantityValueElement = clickedDivQuantitySelect.querySelector(".value");
   
    if(classNameOperator === "value-minus"){
      quantityValueElement.innerText = actionsOperator.minus();
    }
    if(classNameOperator === "value-plus"){
      quantityValueElement.innerText =  actionsOperator.plus();;
    }
  })
}

const actionsOperator = {
  minus: function(){
    return --quantityValueElement.innerText;
  },
  plus: function(){
    return ++quantityValueElement.innerText;
  }
}
```

```css
    body{display: flex;}
    .quantity-select{
        display: flex;
        margin:10px;
    }
    .value-plus{
        font-size: 25px;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-right: 6px;
    }
    .value-minus{
        font-size: 25px;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-left: 6px;
    }
    .value{
        font-size: 25px;
        cursor: default;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>BTN PLUS MINUS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="quantity-select">
        <div class="value-plus">+</div>
        <div class="value">0</div>
        <div class="value-minus">-</div>
    </div>
    <div class="quantity-select">
        <div class="value-plus">+</div>
        <div class="value">0</div>
        <div class="value-minus">-</div>
    </div>
    <div class="quantity-select">
        <div class="value-plus">+</div>
        <div class="value">0</div>
        <div class="value-minus">-</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Be aware that the event.target.parentElement; will get the parent div: `<div class="quantity-select">`

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)to traverse up to the form element:

```
// delegated event handler because Turbolinks is a thing
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  let el = event.target;
  if (!el.matches('.quantity-select>.value-minus, .quantity-select>.value-plus')) {
    return false;
  }
  let quantity = el.closest('form').elements['quantity'];
  let val = parseInt(quantity.value, 10);
  quantity.value = el.classList.contains('value-plus') ? ++val : --val;
});
```

There is also no need for a seperate script tag. Just write an idempotent delegated handler and you'll have an something turbolinks compatible that you can put in your assets pipeline (or packs).